# Chart.js 2.9.4 - setting axis min\max via `afterDataLimits` callback is working incorrectly (while setting via options is working correctly)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a Chart.js **2.9.4** `line` chart (same problem with latest **3.5.1** version) and I want to set yAxis min\max via `afterDataLimits` callback (because I need to calculate axis max and min in runtime, basing on values ​​in datasets):

```js
var data = {
  labels:["0","1","2"],
  datasets: [{
    lineTension: 0,  
    fill: false,  
    data: [0, 10, 4]
  }]
};

var options = {
    animation: false,    
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
                afterDataLimits: function (axis) {
                //Setting axis min\max via callback - yAxis is -2 -> 12
                axis.max = 10.5;
                axis.min = -0.5;
            },
            ticks: {
                //Setting axis min\max via options - yAxis is -0.5 -> 10.5
                //min: -0.5,
                //max: 10.5
            }
        }]
    }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<div id="chartDiv"><canvas id="chart"></canvas></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

**Setting axis min\max via options is working correctly (yAxis is -0.5 -> 10.5):**
[image: Setting axis min\max via options is working correctly (yAxis is -0.5 -> 10.5)]

**Setting axis min\max via `afterDataLimits` callback is working incorrectly (yAxis is -2 -> 12):**
[image: Setting axis min\max via afterDataLimits callback is working incorrectly (yAxis is -2 -> 12)]

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the options?

Comment: @LeeLenalee Because I need to calculate axis max and min in runtime, basing on values ​​in datasets.